# Add more information to @CreatedBy

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I've a Spring Boot 2.3 application. All my entities extends an abtract entity that has some auditing fields like:

```
@CreatedBy
@Column(updatable = false)
protected String createdBy;

@CreatedDate
@Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
protected Instant createdDate;
```

I implemented `AuditorAware`:

```
public class SpringSecurityAuditorAware implements AuditorAware<String> {

    public static final String SYSTEM_USER = "system";

    @Override
    public Optional<String> getCurrentAuditor() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (authentication == null || !authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
            return Optional.of(SYSTEM_USER);
        }

        Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();

        /**
         * If the principal is a CustomUserDetail I access to the name property
         */
        if (principal instanceof CustomUserDetail) {
            CustomUserDetail user = (CustomUserDetail) principal;
            // the sid of the user if not null or the username instead
            String sid = user.getSid() != null ? user.getSid() : user.getUsername();
            return Optional.ofNullable(sid);
        }

        return Optional.of(authentication.getName());
    }
}
```

In `createdBy` field I save the sid (identifier) of the user. In this way I've a reference to the source table and I can keep a link between all changes and the user.
However, for performance reasons, I'd like to save also the full name of the user in each entity.
Is there a clean way to reach this goal? The only thing I can think of is to use an `EntityListener` and set `createdByName` on `@PrePersist` for example.

```
@Component
public class MyEntityListener { 

 @PrePersist
 private void onPrePersist(MyAbstractEntity entity) {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (authentication != null) {
              Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
              if (principal instanceof CustomUserDetail) {
                    CustomUserDetail user = (CustomUserDetail) principal;
                    entity.setCreatedByName(user.getFullName());
              }
        }
 }
}
```

What do you think about? Do you have any other better/clean approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field annotated as `@CreatedBy` can be of any type. I think that one approach could be to create an `AuditUser` class having fields like `userId` and `userFullName`, and annotate it as `@Embeddable` (in case, also with `@AttributeOverrides` to declare how you want your table columns to be named). Then, in your entity you can have an `AuditUser` field annotated with `@CreatedBy` and `@Embedded`, combined with an implementation of `AuditorAware<AuditUser>`. More info on embeddable objects in this [blog post](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-embedded-embeddable) (Baeldung).

If you needed something more specific, you could think of creating something custom, inspired from how Spring implemented the JPA auditing (looking at the classes `AuditingEntityListener`, `AuditingHandler`, and `AnnotationAuditingMetadata`).